# How to replace parts of list given excel data, python

Tags: python

If I have the list = ['a' ,'b', 'c']

and the excel file looks something this like

```
Column 1         Column 2 
a                1
b                2
c                3
```

How can I make a new list that replaces "a" with "1", "b" with "2", etc.

To be clear, I want to make a new list that says  List2 = ["1", "2", "3"], but using the excel sheet.

Basically my question is, how I can I replace a list with the contents of the cells next to it from the excel sheet?

Please note my excel sheet is much larger than this with more complicated names. Also, I have the excel file saved as a pandas dataframe so far.

Thanks.

Comment: If you already had imported excel data as pandas dataframe, why not just [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) your list with the excel?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. I'm not trying to change the excel file. I'm trying to create a new list given the data in the excel. Also, my list isn't the same size as my row count. I'm only using some rows from the excel file, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Because you already used pandas, so you can just simple join excel data with your list.

Or you can create one dict to store the key/value pair, then loop your list to get the value from that dict.

**The codes will be like below:** (*Assuming all keys can be found in excel, you may need to add some validations for real use*):

```
#uses one dict store index
test = ['a' ,'b', 'c']
excel = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
G_indexes = {}
def buildIndexes(data):
    G_indexes[data[0]] = data[1]
    return data

list(map(buildIndexes, excel))
print('normal',list(map(lambda item: G_indexes[item], test)))

#use pandas join
import pandas as pd
df_excel = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                        'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
your_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df_yours = pd.DataFrame({'key': your_list})

df_result = df_yours.join(df_excel.set_index('key'), on='key')
print('pandas',list(df_result['value']))
```

Output:

```
normal [1, 2, 3]
pandas [1, 2, 3]
[Finished in 1.04s]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list only contains strings, you can loop over each element and replace the entries.
The easiest way to read the excel file is using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('filename')  # user read_csv if your file is .csv
df.set_index('Column 1')
new_list = [df[i] for i in old_list]  # old_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

This should work if you have installed pandas and the entries of Column 1 are unique and I didn't missed up the inline loop. Other wise using more basic syntax:

```
new_list = []
for i in old_list:
    new_list.append(df[i])
```